# Multiple classes with the same name?

Tags: css, class

Multiple classes with the same name?
I know it works but is it valid?

```css
.color {color:orange;}
.first .color {color:blue;}
.second .color {color:red;}
```

```
<div class="color">
some text here
</div>

<div class="first">
some <span class="color"> text here</span>
</div>

<div class="second">
some <span class="color"> text here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Those are not multiple classes. It's one class that many elements have. And of course it's valid.

Comment: The [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will tell you. But I don't understand what you mean with "multiple classes with same name", really.

Comment: I often do this for content managed sites so that a user can set the top level colour and then it will cascade so all items with a color class are set to that colour

Comment: my apologies, then. I thought that since I had defined 3 different colors, each would be considered unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's perfectly valid, and perfectly readable. Note particularly that the order the classes are declared in is not important. CSS works on the principle that the most-specific selector wins.

```
.color {color:orange;}
```

> Defines that any element with class **color** is orange.

```
.first .color {color:blue;}
```

> Defines that any element with class **color** *that is a descendent of an element with class **first*** is blue

```
.second .color {color:red;}
```

> Defines that any element with class **color** *that is an descendent of an element with class **second*** is red

Comment: thats perfectly clear, thank you. still, is there a better way to define them? like using selectors instead

Comment: You have it the wrong way around `Defines that any element with class color that is an ancestor of an element with class first is blue`. In actual fact `color` is not an ancestor of `first`. `color` is a descendant of `first` and `first` is an ancestor of `color`.

Comment: @MrCode I'd already spotted that and [edited it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15003322/revisions). See edit 2 in link ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That is a descendant selector:

```
.first .color {color:blue;}
```

An element with class `color` that is a descendant of an element with class `first` will be targeted. Note that this differs from the child selector (`>`) which will only match direct children. The descendant selector matches elements that are at any level descended from the parent.

From [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/descendant):

> **Descendant combinator A B**
>
> A selector of the form "A B" represents an element "B" that is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element "A". A descendant combinator is whitespace that separates two sequences of simple selectors.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but it's not very readable in this case.